# Automatically enter the requested password

Tags: bash, go, automation, passwords, command-prompt

I'm running a Go program that asks me for a password.

The script itself is done like that:

```
fmt.Print("Enter password: ")
bytePassword, err := terminal.ReadPassword(int(syscall.Stdin))
if err != nil {
    return
}
password := string(bytePassword)
```

`terminal` is from `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal` and `syscall` from `syscall` module.

I tried to run the script like:

`echo "mypassword" | ./myscript`

But it doesn't work (it does in the normal way, when I manually enter the password when it's asked)

How can I automatically enter the password here? I thought I was doing it right, but obviously not.

Comment: you can use an [tag:expect]-like tool. go has goexpect: https://github.com/google/goexpect

Comment: Does that mean I have to change the code of the go script? Because this is something I cannot do. Actually I only have the binary, I just know how it's done, but I cannot change it

Comment: you write a new go program with goexpect. this new prog runs your "myscript" with goexpect.

Comment: A small note on terminology: Go is compiled. It is not a scripting language. Therefore there's no such thing as a "Go script".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how i do it with `expect` wrapped in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PASS=secret_pass
CMND=YOUR_COMMAND

expect << EOF
spawn  $CMND
expect {
    "assword:" { send "$PASS\n" }
}
EOF
```

Here's a working example from my [ssh_yes](https://github.com/vaniacer/ssh_yes) project:

```
ssh_yes() {
assword='
    "assword:" { %s }
    "$ "       { send "exit\n" }
'
[[ $2 ]] && pass="send \"$2\n\"" || pass="exit"
printf -v assword "$assword" "$pass"
expect <<  EOF
spawn  ssh $1
expect {
    "yes/no" {
        send "yes\n"
        expect { $assword }
    }
    $assword
}
EOF
}
```